# Does all EVM chains uses 18 decimals for their native token?

Tags: blockchain, evm

I was wondering if all native tokens based on EVM utilizes 18 decimals places. Is there any EVM chains that does't use 18 decimals for their native token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All EVM chains should implement 18 decimals in its native tokens in order to remain compatible with Solidity: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units

```
assert(1 wei == 1);
assert(1 gwei == 1e9);
assert(1 ether == 1e18);
```

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default number of decimal places used in an ERC20 token is 18. This is because Ether has 18 decimal places, and the ERC20 standard was designed to be compatible with Ether. but the token creators can choose to use a different number of decimals if they wish. You can do so by calling `_setupDecimals` in your constructor.

I think tether(USDT) has an [implementation with 6 decimals](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code)

Comment: He is talking about native tokens (like ETH in Ethereum chain), not about ERC20 tokens.